# How to deploy Net Core razor pages app using SFTP?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, ftp, sftp, razor-pages

Note: I have thoroughly read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2 and many other Microsoft docs related to deployment, and none of them helped (also, Azure is not an option for me)

I am trying to deploy my net core razor pages web app to my website domain using Cyberduck SFTP. My website is hosted by 1and1, which supports Net Core (https://www.ionos.ca/help/hosting/net/net-core-21-with-windows-hosting/ ). Apart from consulting the above documentations, I have tried the following approaches that failed:

1) In visual studio, publish my project to folder, and then copy over the files to Cyberduck SFTP.

2) In visual studio, select the FTP publish method to publish my project directly to my website using my username/password for the 1and1 server

For both approaches, the files get published to the server properly but I receive a 403 Forbidden error. I am wondering if the fact that Razor apps bundle index.cshtml to the dll file when published, so that the server cannot find the index.html to start up the default page is the cause of this.  How would a server like 1and1 start a website if it does not have an index.html?

Here is what it looks like on the FTP: Note that it is under the 'Whiteboard' folder instead of '/' but I have repointed the server to look for this folder, so that is not the issue. 
[image]
Has anyone here successfully published an Net Core razor pages web app using FTP like Cyberduck and can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Publishing with FTP should not be a problem. I have done it alot. The web.config file beside your .netcore published files is responsible for this kind of stuffs. If you open it you'll see that it points to the DLL files. 
I think the problem will be resolved with a configuration in you administrative panel. Just ask 1and1 support.

Comment: Have you tried changing the Deployment mode in VS? I had a similiar problem with an external hoster and what fixed it for me was setting the Deployment mode from "Framework-Based" to "Self-Contained" (I hope the translations fit, my VS is not in english, sorry about that). You should be able to find it under Publishing -> Configure -> Settings. What it does is, it hosts the full .NET environment with the application. Drawback is that the filesize of the app will increase alot.

Comment: @AliDoustkani thanks! Contacting support was the last thing on my mind as I kept thinking it had something to do with my end, but I ended up asking support and they solved everything :D

Comment: @Aiyuni Great! So, what was the probelm?

Comment: @AliDoustkani the problem was me being dumb and purchasing a Linux server package instead of Windows server package haha

Comment: @Aiyuni :)) Don't worry! These kind of problems happens all the time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are using a Linux server package instead of Windows service package.